# Android - res sizes for different device types

Tags: android

This is more of a sanity check question.

looking google's resource for laying out bucket sizes here -> https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#TaskUseSWQuali

Buckets should be:

- layout (handset)
- layout-port (handset portrait)
- layout-land (handset landscape)
- layout-sw600dp-port (7" tablet portrait)
- layout-sw720dp-port (10" and greater tablet portrait)
- layout-sw960dp-land (7" tablet landscape)
- layout-sw1024dp-land (10" and greater tablet landscape)

I've tried finding a concise guide but the link above is the best I could do and I'm just making sure I'm reading the graph properly.

Question:  Are the above bucket sizes correct?  Can you provide a little more context and/or suggest more/different sizes?

Comment: You can replace `swXYZdp` with any `XYZ` number...

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm just wondering if these will behave as intended (look in the parenthesis) and are correct sizes for the cut offs

Comment: If you exclude the screen width folders (which I personally do when starting an app), then you only need two layout folder. Regular and land. Generally, one would only use landscape orientation on tablets or TVs

Comment: yeah, we have unique layouts for handset, 7" tablet, and 10" tablet.  I'm just making sure that the above buckets will definitely work

Comment: According to the documentation, they should. If not, feel free to post a question asking why not

Comment: sounds good to me